Most natural way to say "make sure the phone flat on the wall"
If I want to ask the user to make sure his phone is vertically aligned to the wall, what is the best way to say it?

Make sure the phone is flat/lying/vertically aligned? on/against the wall

Is there a better natural way to say it and make it more clear to the user?
Thank you

Are you installing a new land-line phone, or are you talking about  placing the receiver back in the cradle?

No, I am developing an app that measures bone angles on xrays. For the angle to be correct, the phone should be held against the xray viewer that is hanging on the wall (as flat as possible).

The phone needs to be held "flat against the viewer surface" and the viewer and phone need to be level, or both need to be out of level in the same degree. Right?

Can the phone be positioned at first at the viewer's corner, so you can determine the viewer's degree of levelness?  You can assume it is rectangular.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Hadi What your question does not make clear is: whether the app must be activated, whether the phone must be held with the front (app open) against the the x-ray viewer or with the rear camera lens/es against the x-ray viewer. I think what you want to say is: 1. Turn on your mobile phone. 2 Open "my" app. 3. Hold the phone upright with the screen against the x-ray viewer. 4. Do whatever else is required.

I wonder if someone could confuse "flat against the wall" (vertical) with "flat, against the wall" (horizontal). You're best to include a picture and not rely on text. That said "Make sure the phone is flat against the wall" is definitely natural-sounding; whether it's unambiguous I'm less sure.

"What is the most natural way to say [x]" is an off-topic question because (a) it shows no research and (b) it is proofreading.

OP clarified their intent in the comments:

"I am developing an app that measures bone angles on X-rays. For the angle to be correct, the phone should be held against the X-ray viewer that is hanging on the wall (as flat as possible)."

Based on this, the correct way to express it is:
"The phone should be held parallel to the viewer, ensuring no inclination or parallax error between them."
If your audience is unable to understand "parallax error" you might consider using simple language for clarity:
"The phone should be held parallel to the viewer, ensuring no misalignment that could affect accuracy."

I'll note that the instructions from the answer suggest aligning it parallel against the x-ray viewer, whereas possibly OP's intent is to accomplish the alignment by keeping the phone in physical contact with the x-ray viewer.  Also, I would avoiding eliding "x-ray" in "x-ray viewer" for fear of a user thinking viewer refers to themselves (viewing the x-ray on the x-ray viewer) rather than the x-ray reviewer.

@Brian It isn't possible to get the viewers complete image if phone is touching it. As the app measures bone angle, if there is any inclination (parallax error) would occur.
